# Query Comparing Arrays of Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm wondering how I can compare arrays of (nested) objects in Mongoose.

Considering the data below, I would like to get results when the `name` properties match. Could anyone help me with this?

```
    Organisation.find( { 
        $or: [ 
          { "category_list": { $in: cat_list } }, 
          { "place_topics.data": { $in: place_tops } } 
        ] 
      } 
    )
```

Let's say that this is the data stored in my MongoDB:

```
  "category_list": [
      {
          "id": "197750126917541",
          "name": "Pool & Billiard Hall"
      },
      {
          "id": "197871390225897",
          "name": "Cafe"
      },
      {
          "id": "218693881483234",
          "name": "Pub"
      }
  ],
  "place_topics": {
      "data": [
          {
              "name": "Pool & Billiard Hall",
              "id": "197750126917541"
          },
          {
              "name": "Pub",
              "id": "218693881483234"
          }
      ]
  }
```

And let's say that these are the arrays I want to compare against (almost the same data):

```
let cat_list = [
            {
                "id": "197750126917541",
                "name": "Pool & Billiard Hall"
            },
            {
                "id": "197871390225897",
                "name": "Cafe"
            },
            {
                "id": "218693881483234",
                "name": "Pub"
            }
        ]
let place_tops = [
                {
                    "name": "Pool & Billiard Hall",
                    "id": "197750126917541"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Pub",
                    "id": "218693881483234"
                }
            ]
```

Comment: Is the following true? We have a match only if:
 - the arrays to compare against have the same lengths as their corresponding arrays;
 - they contain the same set of ids;
 - records with the same id should have the same name, other fields can be different.

Comment: Well actually, the data stored in MongoDB also contains a string _id so it's false.

Comment: Yes, but you wrote you were interested in comparing names, so I assumed you wanted to check if despite matching the id, the name was the same (up to date or smth). It looks like I misunderstood you.

Comment: No problem, the data i provided isn't the actual stored data, the actual stored data would more look like:
`{ 
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5931bd880472150069e7c"
    }, 
    "name": "Pool & Billiard Hall" 
 }`

I should've store the numeric Ids but I didn't so I have to compare by name :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there are ["multiple conditions"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#specify-multiple-criteria-for-array-elements) required for each array element is when you actually use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/), and in fact "need to" otherwise you don't match the correct element.

So to apply multiple conditions, you would rather make an array of conditions for [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) instead of shortcuts with [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):

```
Organizations.find({
  "$or": [].concat(
    cat_list.map( c => ({ "category_list": { "$elemMatch": c } }) ),
    place_tops.map( p => ({ "place_topics": { "$elemMatch": p } }) )
  )
})
```

**However**, if you take a step back and think logically about it, you actually named one of the properties **"id"**. This would generally imply in all good practice that the value is in fact ""unique".

Therefore, all you really should need to do is simply extract those values and stick with the original query form:

```
Organizations.find({
  "$or": [
    { "category_list.id": { "$in": cat_list.map(c => c.id) } },
    { "place_topics.id": { "$in": place_tops.map(p => p.id) } }
  ]
})
```

So simply mapping both the values and the property to "match" onto the `"id"` value instead. This is a simple ["dot notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) form that generally suffices when you have **one** condition per array element to test/match.

That is generally the most logical approach given the data, and you should apply which one of these actually suits the data conditions you need. For "multiple" use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/). But if you don't need multiple because there is a singular match, then simply do the singular match

Comment: That seems to do the trick, I'm going with the last approach as it's enough to have one match in either statement. Thank you so much!